# Почему при клике на label происходит двойной клик?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть стилизованные радиокнопки. По клику нужно выполнить js-функцию, но она выполняется дважды. Почему происходит двойной клик?

```js
var i = 0;

$(".js-radio label").click(function() {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
});
```

```css
.label {
 display: block;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
 padding: 0 0 0 50px;
  width: 400px;
 height: 52px;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaf1;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 50px;
 color: #4a4a4a;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.label:hover {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px #eaeaf1;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px #eaeaf1;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px #eaeaf1;
}

.label .radio {
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #e8e8e8;
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 15px;
}

.label input {
 display: none;
}

.label input[type=radio]:checked + .radio {
 border: 2px solid #51b905;
 background: #51b905;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff inset;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step js-radio">
        <label class="label">
         <input type="radio" name="option10" value="Менее 10 тыс. руб.">
         <span class="radio"></span> Менее 10 тыс. руб.
        </label>
        <label class="label">
         <input type="radio" name="option10" value="10 - 20 тыс. руб.">
         <span class="radio"></span> 10 - 20 тыс. руб.
        </label>
        <label class="label">
         <input type="radio" name="option10" value="20 - 30 тыс. руб.">
         <span class="radio"></span> 20 - 30 тыс. руб.
        </label>
        <label class="label">
         <input type="radio" name="option10" value="Более 30 тыс. руб.">
         <span class="radio"></span> Более 30 тыс. руб.
        </label>
       </div>
```

:

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно поменять структуру, что бы `inputs` лежали рядом с `labels`, тогда всё должно работать правильно

https://jsfiddle.net/EugeneMelnikov/qxw5s8h0/1/

Добавил пример

Answer (score 0):

А если так?

```
var i = 0;

$(".js-radio").children("label").click(function() {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
});
```